# How to count all the words in a textfile with multiple space characters

Tags: delphi, text-files, pascal, lazarus, cpu-word

I am trying to write a procedure that counts all the words in a text file in Pascal. I want it to handle multiple space characters, but I have no idea how to do it.

I tried adding a boolean function Space to determine whether a character is a space and then do

```
while not eof(file) do
begin    
  read(file,char);
  words:=words+1;
  if Space(char) then
    while Space(char) do
      words:=words;
```

but that doesnt work, and basically just sums up my(probably bad) idea about how the procedure should look like. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, as Tom outlines in his answer, you need a state machine with the two states In_A_Word and Not_In_A_Word and then count whenever your state changes from Not_In_A_Word to In_A_Word.

Something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
var
  InWord: Boolean;
  Ch: Char;
begin
  InWord := False;
  while not eof(file) do begin    
    read(file, Ch);
    if Ch in ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'] then begin
      if not InWord then begin
        InWord := True;
        Words := Words + 1;
      end;
    end else
      InWord := False
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Doesn't work with "Jag äter mycket bönor." (4 words) or "He is a crime-fighting dog." (5 words) or "That's great!" (2 words). I think this is the reason why you should never base the algorithm on "X is a letter", but rather "X is whitespace".

Comment: It does for certain specific definitions of `word` :P

Comment: Great, this idea with some minor modifications helped me do it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andreas "Jag äter mera morötter" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `boolean` variable to indicate whether you are processing a word.

Set it `true` (and increment the counter) on *first only* non-space character.

Set it `false` on a space character.

Comment: This is the general idea in its simplest form, indeed. But there are always edge cases. For instance, how many words are there in "I saw a cat/dog."? Of course, you cannot treat punctuation as whitespace in general, because of the "crime-fighting dogs" or the "dog-loving families" (or "7-Dehydrocholesterol").

Comment: Plus one for basing the algorithm on whitespace testing and not letter testing.

Comment: Of course: the input must be well formed. Using texts produced by average mankind will fail when spaces don't follow punctuation. And based on the language spaces might have been used illegally when hyphens should combine words to one.

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be to read whole file in one string and then use following steps to count words:

```
{$mode objfpc}
uses sysutils; 

var
  fullstr: string = 'this is   a     test  string. '; 
  ch: char;
  count: integer=0; 

begin 
  {trim string- remove spaces at beginning and end: }
  fullstr:= trim(fullstr); 

  {replace all double spaces with single: }
  while pos('  ', fullstr) > 0 do 
    fullstr := stringreplace(fullstr, '  ', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]); 

  {count spaces: }
  for ch in fullstr do
    if ch=' ' then 
      count += 1; 

  {add one to get number of words: }
  writeln('Number of words: ',count+1); 
end.
```

The comments in above code explain the steps.

Output:

```
Number of words: 5
```