# How to accurately count words in a Memo?

Tags: delphi, word-count

I'm trying to make a Notepad clone, with the added feature of a running word count in the status bar. The word count is inaccurate, counting repeated spaces or carriage returns as new words. Here's what I've tried for the word count feature:

```
procedure TFormMain.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  wordSeparatorSet: Set of Char;
  count: integer;
  i: integer;
  s: string;
  inWord: Boolean;
begin
  wordSeparatorSet := [#13, #32]; // CR, space
  count := 0;
  s := Memo1.Text;
  inWord := False;

  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
  begin
    // if the char is a CR or space, you're at the end of a word; increase the count
    if (s[i] in wordSeparatorSet) and (inWord=True) then
    begin
      Inc(count);
      inWord := False;
    end
    else
    // the char is not a delimiter, so you're in a word
    begin
      inWord := True;
    end;
  end;
  // OK, all done counting. If you're still inside a word, don't forget to count it too
  if inWord then
    Inc(count);

  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Words: ' + IntToStr(count);
end;
```

Of course, I'm open to any alternatives or improvements. I really don't understand why this code increases the word count (`count`) with every space and carriage return. I would think after the user hits the space bar (incrementing `count`), the variable `inWord` should now be False, so `if (s[i] in wordSeparatorSet) and (inWord=True)` should resolve to False if the user hits the space bar or Enter key a second time. But that's not what happens.

Comment: Did you see https://rejbrand.se/rejbrand/article.asp?ItemIndex=505? Or this SO question from a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611136/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-words-in-a-given-string. Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877404/how-to-count-all-the-words-in-a-textfile-with-multiple-space-characters.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for responding. I saw one or, maybe, two of your links. I've seen so many I've lost track :-) ... Your 'regarding your confusion' response is very helpful. [Funny addenda: I was about to suggest you write it as an answer because I might select it. Your did just that, mid-sentence.]

Comment: Yeah, I realised I was abusing the comment section! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I really don't understand why this code increases the word count (`count`) with every space and carriage return.

At the first space after a word, you do indeed set `inWord` to `False`. So, if the next character is also a space, you will (erroneously) run `inWord := True`, so if the next (third) character is again a space, you will (erroneously) do `Inc(count)`.

You can also notice that the negation of `(s[i] in wordSeparatorSet) and (inWord=True)` does NOT imply that "the char is not a delimiter" because of the conjunction with `inWord`. The negation of `(s[i] in wordSeparatorSet) and (inWord=True)` is, by [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), `not (s[i] in wordSeparatorSet) or not (inWord=True)`, which is NOT the same thing as `not (s[i] in wordSeparatorSet)`.

A fixed version would look more like

```pascal
function WordCount(const AText: string): Integer;
var
  InWord: Boolean;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  InWord := False;
  for i := 1 to Length(AText) do
    if InWord then
    begin
      if IsWordSep(AText[i]) then
        InWord := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      if not IsWordSep(AText[i]) then
      begin
        InWord := True;
        Inc(Result);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

where `IsWordSep(chr)` is defined as something like `chr.IsWhitespace` but there are many subtleties, as I discuss at length [on my web site](https://rejbrand.se/rejbrand/article.asp?ItemIndex=505).